# Javascript script fail with alerts

Tags: javascript, jquery, alert

I have the following code:

```
$(".zalen").change(function(){
        var number = $(this).val(); 
        $('.Zaal').load('zaal'+ number +'.html');

        var storageName = "zaal" + $(".zalen").val() + '_chairs';
        var chairs = localStorage.getItem(storageName);
        if(chairs == null)
        {
            chairs = "";
        }
        var chairArray = chairs.split(" "); 
        alert(chairArray);
        $("td.chair").each(function(index){
            for(var i=0; i < chairArray.length; i++)
            {
                if(index == chairArray[i])
                {
                    $(this).addClass('reserved');   
                }
            }
        })
    });
```

Note the alert after the split of chairs.

It works perfectly with the alert. but hen i was done with testing and removed the alert. the code stoped working and i have no clue why it does that.

Can anybody help me with this problem.

SOLUTION :

```
$(".zalen").change(function(){
        var number = $(this).val(); 
        $('.Zaal').load('zaal'+ number +'.html', function() {
            var storageName = "zaal" + $(".zalen").val() + '_chairs';
            var chairs = localStorage.getItem(storageName);
            if(chairs == null)
            {
                chairs = "";
            }
            var chairArray = chairs.split(" ");  
            $("td.chair").each(function(index){
                for(var i=0; i < chairArray.length; i++)
                {
                    if(index == chairArray[i])
                    {
                        $(this).addClass('reserved');   
                    }
                }
            })
        });
    });
```

Thank you @jbabey for your solution. Iam very gratefull

Comment: Could you post your HTML too, please? Or better still, put together a jsFiddle > www.jsfiddle.net

Comment: `load()` is asynchronous. you need to put all your code in it's success callback.

Comment: @jbabey This should be an answer. That's the reason alert was necessary.

Comment: Thank you @jbabey, I tried your suggestion and it worked. Iam very gratefull for your help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

jquery's [`load()`](http://api.jquery.com/load/) function performs an asynchronous request for content. you need to wait until that content is ready before acting on it. when you had your alert, the code was paused for long enough for the `load` to finish. any code you have that relies on the content being loaded into `.Zaal` should be in the load's success handler:

```
$(".zalen").change(function(){
    var number = $(this).val(); 
    $('.Zaal').load('zaal'+ number +'.html', function () {
        // put all of this in the complete callback
        var storageName = "zaal" + $(".zalen").val() + '_chairs';
        var chairs = localStorage.getItem(storageName);
        if(chairs == null) {
            chairs = "";
        }
        var chairArray = chairs.split(" "); 
        alert(chairArray);
        $("td.chair").each(function(index){
            for(var i=0; i < chairArray.length; i++) {
                if(index == chairArray[i]) {
                    $(this).addClass('reserved');   
                }
            }
        })
    });
});
```